# Convert Image to vector: FeatureCollection (Error) Computed value is too large

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to convert a GEDI image to vector, but I get the error **FeatureCollection (Error) Computed value is too large**.
Here is my code.

```
var qualityMask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0));
};
var Bound  = ee.FeatureCollection(table);
var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
    .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
    .map(qualityMask)
    .select('rh95')
    .median();
print(dataset1);
var clipped=dataset1.clipToCollection(Bound);
var gediVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
  palette: 'darkred,red,orange,green,darkgreen',
};
var sample=clipped.toInt();
var vectors = sample.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: Bound,
  crs: sample.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,

});
print(vectors);
```

Comment: Can you explain why are you converting the image to vector?  That's generally not a good path in Earth Engine.

Comment: Because I tried to use the GEDI image as a variable input to the random forest algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have different solutions (for reference check [Debugging guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#timed-out:)) :

option 1:

```
print(vectors.limit(50))//or other number less than 5000;
```

option 2: export it as shapefile or csv

```
Export.table.toDrive({
collection:ee.FeatureCollection(vectors),
description: 'example',
folder:'test',
fileFormat: 'SHP',//or 'CSV'
});
```

an example [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9bb5d133e1067fae8559108c37bd1e34)

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply. This helps me a lot, but I still get Error: Computed value is too large when I use my own table output to Drive. (Error code: 3)